# XSLT: Howto output '<' and '>' from XSL transformation?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, escaping

I am building some text snippets from XML documents using XSL transformation. The text can include '<' and '>' (and other special characters) in the output.

Given the following xml as `data.xml`:

```
<SCH>
    <Ship Id="1" Name="Dicke Bertha" OperatingCostsDay="10.0000000" currency="USD" />
</SCH>
```

and the following xsl as `transformation.xslt`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    Schiff: <xsl:for-each select="SCH/Ship"> Id: <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>&#160; <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>&#160; (OC:<xsl:value-of select="@OperatingCostsDay"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="@currency"/>)
    </xsl:for-each>Betriebskosten &#60; 500 USD oder &#62; 1 Mio. USD
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have the problem that the escape sequences `&#60;` and `&#62;` when loading the XSLT:

```
var xslDocument = XDocument.Load("transformation.xslt");
```

The output after the transformation is not - as expected - with the '<' and '>' characters but it has the HTML escape sequences.

```
Schiff:  Id: 1  Dicke Bertha  (OC:10.0000000 USD)
Betriebskosten &lt; 500 USD oder &gt; 1 Mio. USD
```

What can I do here?

For completeness, here is the full code example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var xslDocument = XDocument.Load("transformation.xslt");
        var compiled = new XslCompiledTransform();
        using (var reader = xslDocument.CreateReader())
        {
            compiled.Load(reader);
        }
        var xml = File.ReadAllText("data.xml");
        Console.WriteLine(Transform(compiled, xml));
    }

    public static string Transform(XslCompiledTransform xsl, string xml)
    {
        // allow fragments
        var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto };
        var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto };

        var stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
        var details = new StringBuilder();
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, readerSettings))
        {
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(details, writerSettings))
            {
                xsl.Transform(reader, writer);
            }
        }

        return details.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: So what kind of output do you want, plain text or XML? If you want plain text then use `<xsl:output method="text"/>` in the XSLT and in your C# code don't transform to an XmlWriter but simply a TextWriter or StringWriter or if you think you need to use an XmlWriter then create it with `xsl.OutputSettings` of the `XslCompiledInstance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am building some text snippets

If you are outputting **text**, then set your output method to `text`.  Then your processor will know not to escape characters that are reserved in XML.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    Schiff: <xsl:for-each select="SCH/Ship"> Id: <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>&#160; <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>&#160; (OC:<xsl:value-of select="@OperatingCostsDay"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="@currency"/>)
    </xsl:for-each>Betriebskosten &#60; 500 USD oder &#62; 1 Mio. USD
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
Schiff:  Id: 1  Dicke Bertha  (OC:10.0000000 USD)
Betriebskosten < 500 USD oder > 1 Mio. USD
```

---

Note also that literal text is best put inside `xsl:text` instructions - otherwise you're passing all the unwanted surrounding whitespace to the output.

Comment: Hmm... two unexplained downvotes of a correct answer... I wonder what I should make of it. Probably shrug and move on.

Comment: First: I did not downvote. But, I am getting different results. I think the pinpoint is how to load the XSLT. When I load it with `XDocument.Load()` the escape sequences `&#60;` and `&#62;` will be translated into HTML escape sequences `&lt;` and `&gt;`. The output then will contain exact that, either output method you use.

So the correct answer to my question was provided by @Pranav

Comment: You can see it returning the expected result here: http://xsltransform.net/naZXpWS As for setting up the transformation in C#, I am afraid I don't know anything about that. I suggest you listen to Martin Honnen, who does. In  any case, `disable-output-escaping` is **not** the correct answer here (it rarely is)..

Comment: @MiGro, it doesn't matter how you load the XSLT (although using `XDocument` for the XSLT together with `XslCompiledTransform` is not in any way necessary or useful, the `Load` method of `XslCompiledTransform` can directly do `compiled.Load("transformation.xslt")`). What matters is the output method, you seem to want `<xsl:output method="text"/>`. And in the case you use the API to an XSLT processor, you then need to make sure you use it so that `xsl:output` is honored.

Comment: @MiGro, If you use `XslCompiledTransform` and transform to an `XmlWriter` created yourself then you basically override the `xsl:output`  settings. So either write directly to a StringWriter or TextWriter or Stream or make sure you create an `XmlWriter` with the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.outputsettings(v=vs.110).aspx of your `XslCompiledTransform`.

Comment: @Martin and Michael. Thanks, I got it now. When using `StringWriter` instead of `XmlWriter` (and my own settings) I get the results I want - without adding the `disable-output-escaping` attribute.

Fyi, loading the XSLT into a XDocument was of course not necessary in this SO, but it is necessary with the part of code I am working with. 

+1 for both of you, plus accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

in XSLT, you can try like
Here I have added `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#60;</xsl:text>` and `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#62;</xsl:text>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    Schiff: <xsl:for-each select="SCH/Ship"> Id: <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>&#160; <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>&#160; (OC:<xsl:value-of select="@OperatingCostsDay"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="@currency"/>)
    </xsl:for-each> Betriebskosten  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#60;</xsl:text> 500 USD oder <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#62;</xsl:text> 1 Mio. USD
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great. Is it possible to disable escaping more globally?

Comment: it's a attribute of <xsl:text> only

Comment: and <xsl:value-of/>